# httpmodules - configure to run only once?

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

I've created a httpmodule but it seems to be getting called on every request within a page.

Can it configured to run only once or for a certain file type?

At the minute when a request is made to load an image it runs the module etc..

Any ideas,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to fix that is put some checking within the httpmodule to work out what file is requesting the module to be run and filter it accordingly.